# Pointer Dereferencing = Program Crash

Tags: c, pointers

```
unsigned int *pMessageLength, MessageLength;
char *pszParsePos;

...
//DATA into pszParsePos
...

printf("\nMessage Length\nb1: %d\nb2: %d\nb3: %d\nb4: %d\n",
    pszParsePos[1],pszParsePos[2],pszParsePos[3],pszParsePos[4]);

pMessageLength= (unsigned int *)&pszParsePos[1];

MessageLength = *((unsigned int *)&pszParsePos[1]);

//Program Dies
```

Output:

```
Message Length
b1: 0
b2: 0
b3: 0
b4: 1
```

I'm don't understand why this is crashing my program.  Could someone explain it, or at least suggest an alternative method that won't crash?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You did not mention: what operating system, what microprocessor, when it 'dies' what error do you see?

Comment: It's running ansi C in uClinux on an embedded Blackfin Processor.  It's says "Bus Error" when it 'dies', but I think that's related to one of the Blackfin Peripherals not being stopped properly (but I could certainly be wrong about that).

Comment: Your system might not be able to access unaligned pointers.

Comment: just highlight the code in the editor window and click the little button that looks like 101010.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the code format now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bus error means that you're trying to access data with incorrect alignment. Specifically, it seems like the processor requires `int` to be aligned more strictly than just anywhere, and if your `*pszParsePos` is aligned, say on an `int` boundary (which depends on how you initialize it, but will happen, e.g., if you use `malloc`), it's certain that `&pszParsePos[1]` isn't.

One way to fix this would be constructing `MessageLength` explicitly, i.e., something like

```
MessageLength = (pszParsePos[1] << 24) | (pszParsePos[2] << 16) | (pszParsePos[3] << 8) | pszParsePos[4]
```

(or the other way around if it's supposed to be little-endian). If you really want to type-pun, make sure that the pointer you're accessing is properly aligned.

Comment: That's exactly what was happening.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think is going wrong:

You added in a comment that you are runing on the Blackfin Processor.  I looked this up on some web sites and they claim that the Blackfin requires what are called *aligned* accesses.  That is, if you are reading or writing a 32-bit value to/from memory, then the physical  address must be a an even multiple of 4 bytes.

Arrays in C are indexed beginning with [0], not [1].  A 4-byte array of char ends with element [3].

In your code, you have a 4-byte array of char which:

- You treat as though it began at index 1.
- You convert via pointer casts to a DWORD via 32-bit memory fetch.

I suspect your 4-char array is aligned to a 4-byte boundary, but as you are beginning your memory access at position +1 byte, you get a misalignment of data bus error.

Comment: No, the character array is much longer than 4 bytes, the data I want in located in indices [1] through [4].  I'm seeing what you mean though, and that's helpful.